# Spring 3.1 @PropertySources does not throw Exception if property does not exist

Tags: spring

Although the name of a property in my Configuration class is wrong, Spring does not throw an Exception. The log shows that the key is not found.

```
2012-06-17 05:26:49,545 DEBUG | main | o.s.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver          | Could not find key 'pegaso.cfdiRequest' in any property source. Returning [null]
```

I am using the property in an Environment class in my Configuraton Class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

   @Autowired
  Environment env;

@Bean
public FesaBean fesaBean() {
   FesaBean fesaBean = new FesaBean();  
   fesaBean.setMyProperty(env.getProperty("pegaso.cfdiRequest"));
   return fesaBean;
}
```

**pegaso.cfdiRequest** does not exist in application.properties. Still, I do not get an Exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
env.getRequiredProperty("propertyName")
```

Environment implements PropertyResolver which has such method [Environment.getRequiredProperty()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getRequiredProperty%28java.lang.String%29) solves the issue. If the property is not found a java.lang.IllegalStateException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Per the API for [Environment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html), it returns a null for values that cannot be resolved, so just make a null check in your specific case:

```
if (env.getProperty("pegaso.cfdiRequest")==null)... // variable not resolved
```

Comment: Thanks Biju! I reread the documentation and found the required method.